# Google Chrome Console Copying Variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables

I came across some very interesting behavior in Google Chrome's console when "copying" a variable.

Try the following on a "fresh" Chrome console *one line at a time*:

> var a = "string";
>
> var copy = a;
>
> copy.length; //returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

It turns out that "copy" is a function baked in to chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#copyobject

Copy happens to be an unlucky choice for a variable name in the console but, curiously, if you reassign it twice then it will work (try the following on a new "fresh" console):

> var a = "string";
>
> var copy = a;
>
> var copy = a; //Declare twice
>
> copy.length; //6

Is there any reason why it works this way in the console? This is on 64-bit 43.0.2357.130

Comment: Both return `6` for me.

Comment: In chromes console you can only use local variables so: var a = "string" will not work *correctly* but a = "string" will